# How to write Marathi in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, languages, indic

I need to type following sentences using LaTeX. Can anyone help?

काशक्यनाही?
तुझेनावकायआहे?”
“वाह !कायहलकंहलकंवाटतंय” 
तूकधीयेणारआहेस?
कधीघडले?
मगतुलाधरलेकसे?
तुम्हीकसेओळखले?
कुणीसांगितले?
हेकामकुणीकेले?
कधी, कसे, कुणी, किती
. तुलामारायचेकारणकाय
ऑ
ऒ
ऋ
ऌ
लोकांनाकायसांगायचे?
यावेळीकायकामकाढलेस
राहायचीकायसोयआहे?
कायनिर्णयघेतला?
तेकामझालेका?
तूकधीयेणारआहेस?
तुम्हीकसेओळखले?

To type Marathi in LaTeX I'm using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

{\dn tuJ\? nAv kAy aAh\? }\\
{\dn kA sh-\8{k}y nAhF}\\
{\dn EktF vAjl\?}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{marathi}

\setmainfont{ITF Devanagari Marathi}

\begin{document}

काशक्यनाही? तुझेनावकायआहे?”
“वाह !कायहलकंहलकंवाटतं
य” तूकधीयेणारआहेस? कधीघड
ले? मगतुलाधरलेकसे? तुम्हीक
सेओळखले? कुणीसांगितले? हेकामकुणीकेले? कधी, कसे, कु
णी, किती.

\end{document}
```

The support for Marathi is not really complete as for other languages, though. Use a font on your system that supports the Devanagari script; ITF Devanagari Marathi comes with mine.

[image]

Comment: Polyglossia does support Marathi. You can set main language ``marathi". See https://ctan.org/pkg/latex-mr

Comment: @RohitD.Holkar Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @egreg- my pleasure!

Comment: What if both english and Marathi both has to be there in the same document.