# Language specific feature not working for some glyphs in the same font

Tags: fonts, xetex, indic

Please refer to the questions I have asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393909/stylisticset-command-dose-not-work-for-some-fonts) and the answer which solved my problem.

I have encountered another difficulty. I have used the same code suggested by [Thérès here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393986/135889) with a different font namely Kadwa (github.com/huertatipografica/Kadwa/tree/master/…).

It contents the glyphs (uni0932094D0932.loclMAR and uni0932094D0932.loclMAR) which is localized variants for ल्ल and ल्प respectively.

Now with the code I could get local variants for श and ल, but even though the localized variants for ल्ल and ल्प have same language code mentioned, they are not rendered properly

The code and result image is provides here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{Sanskrit}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/382981
\setmainfont{NotoSerifDevanagari-Regular.ttf} [Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]
\newfontfamily\Kadwaone[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Kadwa}
\newfontfamily    \Kadwatwo[Script=Devanagari,Language=Marathi,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Kadwa}% note the addition of Language=Marathi
\begin{document}
 {\Kadwaone ५, ८, श, ल, क्क, ल्ल, प्ल}

 \bigskip

 {\Kadwatwo ५, ८, श, ल, क्क, ल्ल, प्ल}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This isn’t possible to answer without looking at the mapping tables in the font. That glyph name looks as if it should be a localized form of the ligature U+0932 U+094D U+0932.